# What is the difference between an independent client and a dependent client in terms of MSMQ

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net, msmq

I have a client that has a server (server A) that has a .net app that is trying to write to a MSMQ on another server (server B).  They are getting the error "MSMQ independent clients cannot serve MSMQ dependent clients".

What is the difference between the two, and is there an easy way to make server A independent?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependent clients are (were) clients that didn't have a local MSMQ queue manager but instead used RPC to access a queue manager on another machine. Bit like a terminal services client where you see what's going on but the work is done elsewhere.

If you go to the MSMQ properties in Computer Management on the server, there is a "Server Security" tab; make sure the "Disable Dependent Clients ....." option is unchecked.

What exact line of code generates the error message?

Cheers
John

Comment: Using .Net, it was either the constructor of the MessageQueue class or the the send method.  We ended up discovering that when the client recently installed MSMQ on the machine, they did not have a particular checkbox (Local Storage) checked.  Reinstalling MSMQ with that set fixed it right up.

Comment: Yes, Local Storage checkbox controls dependent client creation. 
I think it was part of the product group's effort to remove awarenmess of dependent client from the product.